# mongoose returning duplicate results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Pretty new to mongo and mongoose.

I have

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
errorHandler = require('./errors'),
ClientSummary = mongoose.model('ClientSummary');


exports.list = function(req, res) { ClientSummary.find().sort('-LastName').exec(function(err, clients) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        console.log(clients);
        res.jsonp(clients);
    }
});
};
```

this returns double results for each client

I copied this from the console

```
[ { _id: '_?\u0007Z?WM???3\u0016?\u0017',
ArchivedDate: Sun Dec 31 0 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
ArchiveDate: Sat Nov 08 2014 17:18:55 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
Archived: false,
Phone: null,
EmailAddress: 'test@test.com',
LastName: 'test',
FirstName: 'test' },
{ _id: '??\u0002otsF???\u000fF\u0010\u0019\n',
ArchivedDate: Sun Dec 31 0 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
ArchiveDate: Sat Nov 08 2014 17:18:55 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
Archived: false,
Phone: null,
EmailAddress: 'test@test.com',
LastName: 'test',
FirstName: 'test' } ]
```

I get this from a query

```
db.clients.find()
{ "_id" : BinData(4,"U/UnaPQyRxqtc1iPJP7Lyw=="), "Contact" : { "FirstName" : "test", "LastName" : "test", "EmailAddress" : "test@test.com", "Phone" : null, "PhoneSecondary" : null }, "Address" : null, "Source" : null, "SourceNotes" : "asdf", "Archived" : false, "ArchivedDate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "StartDate" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Raif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why you are saying that you have duplicate results in the first query. The `_id`s are different, so, it looks like there are two different objects.

Further, I also think that the second query that you have refers to a different collection; i.e. `clients`, while the first query refers to the collection `clientsummary`.

For example, use the mongo shell, connect to the db *, and try the following two:

```
> show collections
```

If I am right, you have both `clients` and `clientsummary` as collections in your db. Then, also try

```
> db.clientsummary.count()
```

This should return 2.

Note, that it might be the case that you have `clientSummary` instead of `clientsummary` as collection in your db, or even `clientsummarys`/`clientSummarys` or `clientsummaries`/`clientSummaries` as mongo/mongoose will use the plural for the collection and an `s` is usually attached in the end of the word referring to the collection. Just use the right name.

(*) You can connect to the db `mydb` (where the collections you are referring to can be found) using the command:

```
$ mongo --shell localhost/mydb
```

(Assuming you have `mydb` on localhost.)

Comment: christ have mercy.  I blame the screaming kids.  How embarrassing.  Ok, I"m going to mark yours as the correct answer, but then I'm going to try to delete this to erase the evidence

Comment: Hey, it can happen to anyone. Especially if you are new to mongo/mongoose. No worries.

Comment: Same issue for me but slightly different cause. I was using mongoimport (grunt task) to upload the data but wasn't dropping the database before adding in the items. Every time I ran the grunt task, it would add a dupe.